# Not able to delete element from array in mongoose document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I tried to update the array in a different method and none of them worked.

The Schema example:

```
const exampleSchema = new mongoose.Schema{
id : String,
list :Array // will store other id's
}
const Example= mongoose.model("Example", exampleSchema );
```

in the client(react with Axios) I used delete and patch requests method to try to update the document. (in this example I attach the patch request)

```
 const { data, status } = await axios.patch("url", {
      userId: someId,
      friendId : someOtherId,
    });
```

in Server (nodejs)

```
router.patch("url", async (req, res) => {
  try {

    await Example.updateOne(
      { _id: req.body.friendId },
      {
        $pull: {
          pending: req.body.userId,
        },
      },
      { new: true }
    );
```

I tried also use findOneAndUpdate , also tried $pullAll / $eleMatch and more, none off them not update Example list (array).

**EDIT**: if I compare some values i got the follow

```
//first convert strings from request to object id 
req.body.userId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.body.userId);// 62cc574fd6aa8d638712e6a8 
req.body.friendId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.body.friendId);//
62cc574fd6aa8d638712e6a8

//compare between request converted to object id to the element in that array
 const user = await Example.findOne({ _id: req.body.userId });

   console.log(req.body.friendId == user.pending[0]); // false
    console.log(req.body.friendId, user.pending[0]); // 62cc574fd6aa8d638712e6a8 62cc574fd6aa8d638712e6a8
    console.log(typeof req.body.friendId, typeof user.pending[0]); // object object
```

Why did I get false in the comparison? I'm pretty sure this is the key that prevent me from delete element in that array but I'm not sure how to fix it

Comment: make sure the `req.body.friendId` and `req.body.userId` are matching values. Also, you don''t need the brackets around the `req.body.userId`.

Comment: @prasad_ they both object id that stored as a string. if i search by id only i can find the document. if i search one by id and by array containt that id i got null from search.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$pull: { list : req.body.userId }`?

Comment: @robertklep yea it is. i edit in orginal post. also i found the solution i will publish it here as an answere . (with question inside the answere)

Answer (score 0):

Ok so after a lot of trials and error i found the solution but not understand why its worked.

first off all i compared the value from request to the value inside list.
the request return type of strings while data stored as follow

```
{list :Array } // i thought in this way the data also stored as string when i push other id, but appeare  i pushed object id.
```

then i convert the req.body variables into ObjectId

see code for push methode

```
user.pending.push(friend._id); // stored as objectId
await user.save()
```

the patch request:

```
//convert from str to objectId
const ReqUserId = await mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.body.userId);
    const ReqFriendId = await mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.body.friendId);
```

then the pull work

```
const friend = await Example.updateOne(
      { _id: req.body.friendId },
      {
        $pull: {
          list: ReqUserId,
        },
      },
      { new: true }
    );
```

Comment: $pull is used to remove values from an array.
As you're performing removing of object from an array. as record is already exists then no need to write second argument {new: true}.

Comment: the second argument was just for console log, u are right . thanks